# Netflix-esque list sequencing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to allow users to specify the sequence of items in the same way that I can sort my Netflix Queue.  For example, given a view:

```
 #  |  Item Name
----+------------
 1  |  one
 2  |  three
 3  |  four
 4  |  two
```

If the user changes the order for Item Name "two" to "2" and saves, then they should see:

```
 #  |  Item Name
----+------------
 1  |  one
 2  |  two
 3  |  three
 4  |  four
```

I've tried using a before_save:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  before_save :sequence_items

  def sequence_items
    items.sort{|f,s|f.number <=> s.number}.each_with_index do |item, index|
      item.update_attributes(:number => index + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

but this results in:

```
 #  |  Item Name
----+------------
 1  |  one
 2  |  three
 3  |  two
 4  |  four
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I can use the [acts_as_list plugin](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list).  I renamed the `number` attribute in the `Item` table to `position`, then modified code as below:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  acts_as_list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  before_save :sequence_items

  def sequence_items
    items.each_with_index do |item, index|
      item.insert_at(item.position || index + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Now whenever the list is saved each item will be inserted at the provided position.  I have many existing items that do not have a position value so I added the `|| index + 1` to ensure that they get assigned a position at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists) what you're looking for?

Comment: That's an excellent resource and I may well try it out.  I was hoping to have the manual option for those who don't have javascript.  My problem is that I don't know how to prioritize the user changed items so they appear above the unchanged items that have the same number.

Comment: If I recall (I cancelled my Netflix subscription a while ago) Netflix has little text fields with the queue position, correct? That could be your non-JS fall back. To your second point if each item has a position, as it does in the Railscasts episode, then you don't need to "prioritize" the user changed items since each position has it's own unique value in the list. When you move #1 to #5, #2-5 all move up one.

Comment: You are correct about the text field, that's exactly what I want.  With your #1-#5 example, if I edit #5 and type '1', then save, I expect the item that was at the end to be at the beginning.  What happens is the item that was at the end (#5) becomes #2, the old, unchanged #1 remains at the top.  Take another look at the example I show in the question imagining that the first column contains text boxes

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your concern is. If you move an item in the list then you need to adjust the position of the other items. See the `sort` method in the Railscasts episode.

Comment: When I save, the params get passed like:   Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"42", "list"=>{"items"=>{"0"=>{"number"=>"1", "name"=>"one"}, "1"=>{"number"=>"2", "name"=>"three"}, "2"=>{"number"=>"2", "name"=>"two"}, "3"=>{"number"=>"4", "name"=>"four"}}}}.  How will the `sort` action shown work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know too much about Rails (or Ruby, or programming), but I looked at Ruby's Array documentation and the insert() and delete_at() methods gave me an idea.

Have a sequence column in your items table (starting a 0), and then make an array of item objects (or even just item_id on the backend).

```
            0 1 2
    array = A B C
 user wants B A C

array.insert(0, array.delete_at(1))

            0 1 2
    array = B A C
```

If they can make many changes at once, then this will obviously shift the indices over after each insert. Which means you should just delete by item_id instead.

```
array.insert(0, array.delete(item.id))
```

The delete method returns the value of what's deleted. By making sequence synonymous with the utility array's positions, it makes the logic easier.

Once all changes are complete, you can just map the new array positions to the items' sequence values.